# Cardinality of a finite algebra

Tags: real-analysis

If $\mathcal{R}$ is an algebra (closed under finite union, differences and $X\in \mathcal{R}$) over $X$ and $\mathcal{R}$ is finite, how can we show that $|\mathcal{R}|$ is a power of $2$?

Any hint? Thanks.

Comment: Hint: Every finite algebra is generated by a partition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT:** Show that $\cal R$ is isomorphic to $\mathcal P(A)$ where $A$ is the set of atoms (non-empty elements of $\cal R$ that have no proper subsets in $\cal R$ except the empty set).